# iOS sync software firefox beta

Tags: ios

The [Bookmarks On The Go iOS app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bookmarks-on-the-go/id550037184?mt=8) has a "Use custom server" option where a server URL is manually entered.

Where do I obtain this server URL?

Comment: I assume you mean Firefox 29 with the new Firefox Sync? (that's not a beta anymore... FYI)

Answer (score 1):

Firefox Sync allows the use of a server other than the official server provided by Mozilla, and [it is possible to set one up yourself](http://docs.services.mozilla.com/howtos/run-sync-1.5.html). The "Use custom server" option is provided to allow for this.